# In Excel or VBA shearch for substring in list of strings and return values from another column

Tags: excel, vba, string, list, search

I have the columns below in TestConfigs and I need to check in "Corner" which corners from the worksheet Commun are in "Corner" from TestConfigs and return the adjacent shortname for each corner found, so for example in the bluetooth row, in Shortname I should have VNO/LEP.

| Corner | ShortName |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TC_POWER_DOWN/TC_OPENS |  |  |  |  |
| TC_VNOM/LOOSEVEFUSEP |  |  |  |  |
| TC_NONE/TC_VNOM/TC_OPENS |  |  |  |  |
| TC_POWER_DOWN/TC_OPENS |  |  |  |  |
| TC_POWER_DOWN/LOOSEVEFUSER |  |  |  |  |

[Worksheet TestConfigs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCbzV.png)

| Corner | ShortName |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TC_POWER_DOWN | PWD |  |  |  |
| TC_OPENS | OPS |  |  |  |
| TC_SHORTS | SHT |  |  |  |
| TC_VNOM | VNO |  |  |  |
| LOOSEVEFUSER | LER |  |  |  |
| LOOSEVEFUSEP | LEP |  |  |  |
| TC_NONE | NON |  |  |  |
| TC_OPNOM | OPN |  |  |  |

[Worksheet Commun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWBR7.png)

What I used so far:
`=INDEX(Table4[ShortName]; AGGREGATE(15; 6; ROW($1:$8)*SIGN(MATCH("*"&Table4[Corner]&"*";TestConfigs!C3; 0)); 1))`

But this only sends one of the adjacent values. Is there a way to make a loop over it in VBA, adding the "/" separator, where I can change some of the values in the formula, or an easier way to do it?

Thank you for all the help

Comment: Yes, there are ways to accomplish your goal using VBA, Power Query or depending on your version, worksheet formulas.  But your screenshot of data is almost useless. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful **edit your question** to post it as **text**, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).  *Enter the output of the generator as **code.***

Comment: A link only comment: https://www.xelplus.com/excel-lambda-function-explained/ --> the tutorial is really brilliant and I think it covers exactly what your are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the Corner string and lookup each individual substring in the table.

The following will work in recent versions of **Windows** Excel that have the `TEXTJOIN` function:

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",,VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A3,"/","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s"),Table1,2,FALSE))
```

*Note: the lookup table is set as a **Table**, so that the range will auto-adjust, but you can change this if you need to*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's getting just one value still. I debbuged a bit, and the function gets well all the corners, but at the vlookup there's only one value that is returned.

Comment: @MateusSantosValença perhaps some difference between your pasted data and your real data. Obviously, from the screenshot, it works well here.

Comment: Yeah, since I'm using a french config all the commas need to be semmicolons, but that's all I've changed. The table1, you put it in the formula starting bythe column names or by the values ? I tested both, but just to be sure

Comment: Those are my results when I debbug for the first line, for example(A3):

`=TEXTJOIN("/";;VLOOKUP({"TC_POWER_DOWN";"TC_OPENS"};Table4;2;FALSE))`

`=TEXTJOIN("/";;"PWD")`

Comment: @MateusSantosValença. The table range for **Table1** on my worksheet is `G2:G10`.  And it is a **Table** (I used Format as Table to create it).

Comment: @MateusSantosValença I suppose you could try using `XLOOKUP`: 
 `=TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,XLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A3,"/","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s"),Table1[Corner],Table1[ShortName]))` or even try confirming the formula as an array formula, by holding down `ctrl+shift` when hitting `enter`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't know why it doesn't work, but for the moment my team and I, we decided to do a different approach. I won't be using this solution, we will leave this column for the user to fill using a dropdown list.